# Nested strong parameters error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are trying to create a user that has one address. Address is another model and has the "has_one/belongs_to" relationship.
this is the json we receive

```
{ "user": {
  "username": "Dave",
  "password": "superpass",
  "password_confirmation": "superpass",
"email": "dave@gmail.com",
"email2": "dave2@gmail.com",
"firstname": "Bob",
"lastname": "Bave",
"birthdate": "02-07-94",
"address": {
"address": "15 landing street",
"zipcode": "75018",
"city": "Paris",
"country": "France"
}
}}
```

and the is our controller with the strong parameters.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate, only: :update

  def create
    begin
      p user_params_create[:address_attribute]
      u = User.new(user_params_create)
      u.address = Address.new(user_params_create[:address_attribute])
      u.save
      head :created
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
      Rails.logger.error e.message
      head :bad_request
    end
  end

  def update
    u = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    u.update_attributes(user_params_update)
  end

  private
  def user_params_create
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :email2, :firstname, :lastname, :birthdate, :password, :password_confirmation, :address_attribute => [:address, :zipcode, :city, :country])
  end

  def user_params_update
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :email2, :firstname, :lastname, :birthdate, :address => [:address, :zipcode, :city, :country])
  end
end
```

The creation of the user works, but the address's field are nil.
Any idea why?

Comment: try :address_attributes param

Answer (score 2):

Ok we solved it by modifying the json to

```
{ "user": {
  "username": "Dave",
  "password": "superpass",
  "password_confirmation": "superpass",
"email": "dave@gmail.com",
"email2": "dave2@gmail.com",
"firstname": "Bob",
"lastname": "Bave",
"birthdate": "02-07-94",
"address_attributes": {
"address": "15 landing street",
"zipcode": "75018",
"city": "Paris",
"country": "France"
}
}}
```

Adding "address_attributes in it. The controller now sees all the params. Thx to nicooga for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The name of the param is miss typed. Change it to:

```
def user_params_create
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :email2, :firstname,
   :lastname, :birthdate, :password, :password_confirmation,
   :address => [:address, :zipcode, :city, :country])
end
```

You got

```
Address(#70254790661320) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70254756417360)`
```

because, well, the setter `User#address=` expects an `Address` object no the params hash you are giving to it.

To enable initializing nested models through the parent you should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address`, and use the setter `address_attributes` instead.

```
class User
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

User.new(name: 'Roger', bleh: 'asdf',
  address_attributes: { zip: 213123, etc: 2 })
```

Check http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Remember to white list the correct attrs:

```
def user_params_create
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :email2, :firstname,
   :lastname, :birthdate, :password, :password_confirmation,
   address_attributes: [:address, :zipcode, :city, :country])
end
```

Comment: I tried, but i get an error 50 "Address(#70254790661320) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70254756417360)"

Comment: The problem is another now. The setter `address=` expects a ruby object. Not a hash of parameters. Use the setter `address_attributes` instead, check http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Comment: I did as you say it still null :( but in your example you do not use strong whitelist parameters, could it be the cause of the error?

Comment: Most probably. You have to white list the correct attributes.

Comment: i did exactly this  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :email2, :firstname, :lastname, :birthdate, :password, :password_confirmation, address_attributes: [:address, :zipcode, :city, :country]) but still nil. When you create it you need to use only User.new(user_params_create) or also  Address.new(user_params_create[:address_attributes])? maybe this is wrong

Comment: There's a lot of steps in the middle. You may have whitelisted the params, but the params are not present. Are you sending `user[address_attributes]` to the controller? I recommend you debug the process step by step using ruby's core `debugger` or [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry).

Comment: Well you can see in the controller i posted what i'm sending, i think it might be wrong